# Override CSS-Property of child div in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

Currently I'm using the [progressbar](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/progressbar) of `ng2-bootstrap` in the GUI of my website. The HTML which I use for this step  is very simple:

```
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-4">
    <progressbar  max="100" class="progress-striped" [value]="progress">{{progress}}%</progressbar>
  </div>
```

This gets rendered into the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-4">
    <progressbar class="progress-striped" max="100">
        <div progress="" max="100" class="progress" style="height: 30px;">
            <bar>
                <div aria-valuemin="0" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="min-width: 0px; width: 0%;" ng-reflect-initial-classes="progress-bar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="0%">
                    0%
                </div>
            </bar>


        </div>
    </progressbar>
</div>
```

*I removed some angular directives to improve the readability*

The height of the progressbar is set in the second `div` within the css-class progress, which I can not access, because it is set in the provided source code of the component. Also the innermost `div` is the one I would need to access if I want to change the font-size.

I tried to override the style in the parent to set the height, but the progress class is more specific and therefore I could not override it.

I found a not very pretty solution which uses `ElementRef` and `Renderer`, but this scales very bad and will get messy if there are multiple `progressbars`(ATM I'm trying to access a second progressbar):

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('progressbar').querySelector('div'), 'height', '30px');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('progressbar').querySelector('div').querySelector('bar').querySelector('div'), 'font-size', '15px');
  }
```

Are there better approaches to solve this problem? As last resort I could try to adjust the source code of the component to access both values, but actually I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention specificity as the problem. If that's the case, using `!important` is a solution. Anything marked with `!important` will gain top-specificity and cannot be overridden by any other non-!important CSS rule or inline styles. 
When put in your `global.css` file this should work for all progressbars.
It might not work from within your `component.css` due to view encapsulation.

```
progressbar > div[progress] {
  height: 30px !important;
}

progressbar > div[progress] > bar > .progress-bar {
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: It works, nice! If I remember correctly I tried this solution, but I put the css code in the components.css file.  Now I looked up the topic view encapsulation and with ViewEncapsulation set to None it works with the component.css file, too